# Cygwin 2.9.0 cat/tac Commands Fail on Large Files when Piping to grep -q -m1

Tags: linux, windows, grep, cygwin, cat

I am seeing some odd behavior using Cygwin x64 2.9.0 on Windows 10 Pro x64.  The command I am attempting to run is the following:

```
tac <file> | grep -q -m1 -F "literal string"
```

The above command succeeds on all small files that I throw at it (small means <= 15kB).  It also succeeds if the final occurrence of `literal string` is near the start of the file (e.g., `literal string` appears near the top of the file and nowhere else).  Finally, it also succeeds when neither of the {`-q`, `-m1`} flags is passed to the `grep` command.

However, when the file is around 680kB, and the `literal string` appears near the end of the file, then the `tac` command prints "tac: write error" to STDERR.  Despite this error, the command appears to have succeeded, printing the matching line to output (when the `-q` flag is omitted) and getting the appropriate return value from `grep`.

Further testing has revealed that this same error occurs when using `cat`, except the `literal string` must appear near the start of the file to generate the error, and the generated error is "cat: write error: No space left on device".

Note that this only occurs if at least one of the {`-m1`, `-q`} options is passed to the `grep` command, the match is near the first processed line of the file (for `cat` it is near the beginning, for `tac` it is near the end), and the file is large.

I have run the `df` command, and it reports 14 MB available on the Cygwin drive, with 60 GiB free on the actual disk.  I know I could simply redirect STDERR to the NUL device, but that seems like a hacky work-around.  Does anyone know how to fix this properly?

**BEGIN EDIT**

I found [another report](https://medium.com/@yestyle/cat-write-error-due-to-cygwin-pipe-problem-c814ab54a09a) of the same error from May 2017, but no solution was presented.  The OP of the other post does indicate that he thinks this is a pipe buffer size limitation (perhaps on Windows, perhaps in Cygwin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered a few work-arounds.  Simply change the command:

```
tac <file> | grep -q -m1 -F "literal string"
```

to one of:

```
bash -c "tac <file> | grep -q -m1 -F 'literal string'"
stdbuf -o L tac <file> | grep -q -m1 -F "literal string"
```

I think the first works because it is using a Linux pipe, and the second because it forces the `tac` command output to be line-buffered. Both of these forms make the error go away.

Since this works, I'm guessing the issue is that `grep` stops processing the input buffer once it finds the first match, but `tac` keeps processing input.  Once the buffer is full (probably 64kiB), the buffer blocks and `tac` exits with the specified error.  However, since `tac` successfully processed the line I care about before crashing, everything is working as intended.

Timing these options indicates that the call to `bash` is the faster option.  This is probably because using the Linux pipe, `tac` is able to return immediately once `grep` finds the first match.